# How to use DATA ATTRIBUTE to add background image to an anchor tag with HTML and CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to add a background image to an Anchor tag when value is "ENGLISH" and "FRENCH"

I was able to make it work when the echoed php value was a digit using DATA-ID this way

HTML AND PHP:

```
<li><a href="#" class="pjMbSelectorLocale" data-id="<?php echo 
$locale['id'];?>"><?php echo pjSanitize::html($locale['title']); ?></a></li>
```

CSS:

```
li a[data-id="1"]{
background- 
image:url("img/flags/united- 
kingdom.svg");
background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;display: inline- 
block;
}
  
li a[data-id="2"]{
background-image:url("img/flags/france.svg");
background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;display: inline- 
block;
}
```

now I am trying to do the same when the echoed value is not an ID (1 or 2) but a text ("English" and "French") with this statement:

```
<button>
  <a href="#" data-value="<?php echo $selected_lang;?>"></a>
</button>
```

And I can't seem to figure out how to manipulate it in css

Update: there seems to be a problem with the php, whenever I add the anchor tag, the echoed text disappears: initial php was:

```
<button>
<?php echo $selected_lang;?>
</button>
```

using dev tools, I can see the value being passed into the data-value and the css going with either options. but the browser doesn't not render the text nor the image

---

## Solved

Solution:

the image was being hidden by a background-image:none default property and also I had to apply a height and width.

```
a[data-value="English"]{
background- 
image:url("img/flags/united- 
kingdom.svg");
background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;display:inline- 
block;width: 20px;height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `a[data-id="2"]` means "`<a>` with a `data-id` attribute value of `"2"`". As you might assume, `a[data-value="French"]` would mean "`<a>` with a `data-value` attribute of `"French"`".

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
li a[data-value='ENGLISH']{
    ...
}
li a[data-value='FRENCH']{
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes I did, and in that case, even the text disappears. the displayed text is either French or English and the tag is empty, no text ,no background image

Comment: @Gad Did it work out eventually? You marked the answer accepted. If not maybe give more details?

Comment: What you suggested was correct, but some other things were causing the issue. I have updated my post with the solution. thanks!